# Haskell: When declaring a class, how can I use a type variable that is not immediately in the constructors?

Tags: haskell

I want to define a function, `<-?` to check whether an element is in a list/set/map.

```
module Test where
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set

class Memberable a where
    (<-?) :: b -> a -> Bool
instance Memberable [x] where
    (<-?) = elem
instance Memberable (Map.Map k v) where
    (<-?) = Map.member
instance Memberable (Set.Set x) where
    (<-?) = Set.member
```

The type variable `b` in the class declaration should be the type of element I want to check. However, this doesn't work for Haskell.

```
Test.hs:8:13:
    Couldn't match type 'b' with 'x'
      'b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for (<-?) :: b -> [x] -> Bool at Test.hs:8:5
      'x' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at Test.hs:7:10
    Expected type: b -> [x] -> Bool
      Actual type: b -> [b] -> Bool
    Relevant bindings include
      (<-?) :: b -> [x] -> Bool (bound at Test.hs:8:5)
    In the expression: elem
    In an equation for '<-?': (<-?) = elem
```

How can I use `b` in the class declaration, but still make the types coincider?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### using `TypeFamilies`

The problem is that you somehow have to connect `b` with your collection (the elements in it) - there are several ways to do this but I think a rather nice one is using [TypeFamilies](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Test where

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set

class Memberable a where
  type ElemT a :: *
  (<-?) :: (ElemT a) -> a -> Bool

instance Eq x => Memberable [x] where
    type ElemT [x] = x
    (<-?) = elem

instance Ord k => Memberable (Map.Map k v) where
    type ElemT (Map.Map k v) = k
    (<-?) = Map.member

instance Ord x => Memberable (Set.Set x) where
    type ElemT (Set.Set x) = x
    (<-?) = Set.member
```

As you can see I added an additional `type` *member* to class that will hold the type of the elements used (so you can use them for your `(<-?)` in the very next line).

I also added the needed constraints for your instances - those do really come from the used functions like `elem`, `Map.member` and `Set.member`.

---

### using `MultiParamTypeClasses`

here is the one @dfeuer was hinting at (or so I think):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module Test where

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set

class Memberable e a where
  (<-?) :: e -> a -> Bool

instance Eq x => Memberable x [x] where
    (<-?) = elem

instance Ord k => Memberable k (Map.Map k v) where
    (<-?) = Map.member

instance Ord x => Memberable x (Set.Set x) where
    (<-?) = Set.member
```

#### remark:

I think with this approach you might want to add this [`FunctionalDependency`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) too, as you clearly have such a dependency between the collection `a` and it's elements `e` here ;)

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Memberable e a | a -> e where
  (<-?) :: e -> a -> Bool
```

Comment: Some mention should be made of the standard higher-kinded approach and perhaps also the MPTC one.

Comment: sure - never thought that this should be the default or the only answer ;) - it's just the one that came to mind first (and is reasonable nice IMO) - if you want I can add something - or you can add your own answer ;)

Comment: I think the fact that the higher kinded once is standard Haskell makes it notable, although the other approaches are also solid.

Comment: You almost surely want fundeps for the mptc. Bedtime for me though!

Comment: @dfeuer - you posted this just as I was editing the answer ;) (it just took me some time to check the syntax and lookup the link)

Comment: @Alec I really did not wish for you do remove your answer! If I had seen that you got this already I would not have included it (I only saw the second answer a few minutes ago)- please consider undeleting yours - I will upvote it as soon as you added those constraints and if you like I will delete the parts mentioning MPTC from mine

Comment: hi @dfeuer, what's the standard higher-kinded approach? `Map` and `[]` have a different kind and I can't think about an approach using `Map k` and `[]` right now that somehow brings the `k` into scope (without being beyond `Haskell2010`).

Comment: @ibotty, I think you'd have to flip `Map` with a newtype to get the key type on the other side. It's not as nice as the type family approach.